# Rails - naming levels in a tree

Tags: ruby, tree, ruby-on-rails-4, hierarchy

I have organizations that are arranged as a tree.  I have a request to have different naming schemes for the different roots in a tree.  One user may want to the top level of his tree named "Corporate" above "Region" followed by "Division", while another may want to have "Sections" underneath "All".  Everyone has their own internal terminology that they want to have displayed on forms and such.

There are plenty of gems out there for simply managing a hierarchical relationship, and I don't think any of them are necessarily better or worse for this.  I'm new to rails, coming from a more SQL heavy background.  Writing a query to get what I want is pretty trivial, especially when keeping track of the depth of a node, but that doesn't seem like the rails way.  I had an idea that I could just maintain an organization_scheme_id in the organizations table, but getting from there to relating it to the actual level isn't so clear.

The following schema/models are assuming I'm using Ancestry, but I'm not married to any of it in the least.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry :cache_depth => true, :orphan_strategy => :adopt, :depth_cache_column => :depth
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_one :organization_scheme
end

class OrganizationLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_one :organization_scheme
end

class OrganizationScheme < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :organization_level
end

create_table "organization_levels", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.uuid     "id",                     null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "depth"
  t.uuid     "organization_scheme_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "organization_levels", ["organization_scheme_id", "depth"], name: "index_organization_levels_on_organization_scheme_id_and_depth", using: :btree

create_table "organization_schemes", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.uuid     "id",         null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "organizations", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.uuid     "id",                     null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "string"
  t.integer  "depth"
  t.string   "ancestry"
  t.uuid     "organization_scheme_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "organizations", ["ancestry"], name: "index_organizations_on_ancestry", using: :btree
add_index "organizations", ["organization_scheme_id", "depth"], name: "index_organizations_on_organization_scheme_id_and_depth", using: :btree

create_table "organizations_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.uuid "user_id"
  t.uuid "organization_id"
end

add_index "organizations_users", ["organization_id", "user_id"], name: "index_organizations_users_on_organization_id_and_user_id", using: :btree
add_index "organizations_users", ["user_id", "organization_id"], name: "index_organizations_users_on_user_id_and_organization_id", using: :btree
```